# Python Adding contact on Google Contacts

Tags: python, google-contacts-api

Do someone know how to add a new contact to my google account via python?

I didn't find how to do it in the reference:
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/reference

I want to add contact and **I have only phone number and name.**

Does someone know how to do it?

Comment: If you are using `python-3.x`, it is now supported. You can try the code in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40320191/create-a-google-contact-with-python3?rq=1). But the post indicates that "This client library is supported but in maintenance mode only. We are fixing necessary bugs and adding essential features to ensure this library continues to meet your needs for accessing Google APIs. Non-critical issues will be closed. Any issue may be reopened if it is causing ongoing problems."

Answer (score 2):

I am writing down the steps and also adding some reference link, such that you will have better understanding

- You can use `Google Oauth2` to get access to the Google Contact and need to enable `Contact API and People API`
- Google Contact API

  - Ref to Enable API: https://www.themarketingtechnologist.co/google-oauth-2-enable-your-application-to-access-data-from-a-google-user/
  - Ref to Enable API: https://medium.com/@pablo127/google-api-authentication-with-oauth-2-on-the-example-of-gmail-a103c897fd98
- Need to enable People API - to work with contacts

  - Enable: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/library/people.googleapis.com?
  - Note: For read and write access to users' contacts, use the People API, which provides both contact and profile information using JSON instead of the older GData protocol.
- Google Oauth2

  - Google Consele > credentials > Web client 1 > Authorized redirect URIs >> Add
  - To add and `Authorized redirect URIs` the domain must be added to the authorized domains list before submitting.
  - Google Consele > OAuth consent screen > Authorized domains >> Add Here
- Action you can do after getting Google Contact access.

  - Methods: https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/
  - CreateContact details: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/library/people.googleapis.com?project=contact-60659
  - Get user data: https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people.connections/list?apix_params=%7B"resourceName"%3A"people%2Fme"%2C"personFields"%3A"emailAddresses"%7D
- **NOTE**: Please keep safe your Client_id, Secret_id and API key